# Use the attr() function inside a new plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know if it's possible to use the `attr()` function inside a new plugin :

```
(function ($) {
     $.fn.resetColor = function() {
        var oldColor=this.attr("memColor");
        this.css('background-color',oldColor);
     };
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried the code above but it doesn't work. I'm sure the `memColor` attribute exists because I've tested it with an alert in the `$(document).ready` block.

Comment: The issue is that if there is more than one element in the jQuery collection, then `this.attr()` is only going to retrieve the `memColor` attribute from one element in the collection and then that will be applied to all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery plugin [authoring guidelines](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) recommend this method:

```
(function ($) {
     $.fn.resetColor = function() {
         return this.each(function() {
            var elem = $( this );

            var oldColor = elem.attr("memColor");
            elem.css('background-color',oldColor);
         };
     });
}(jQuery));
```

1. Assume the plugin is called on a set of elements.
2. Obtain the jQuery wrapped element to work with.

Also be aware that there is a difference between *properties* ([`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)) and *attributes* ([`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)), the former refers to properties on JavaScript DOM [HTMLElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), while the later refers to HTML attributes as they are specified in the markup. And jQuery makes this distinction also starting with version 1.6:

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

---

**Demo:**

```js
    (function ($) {
         $.fn.resetColor = function() {
             return this.each(function() {
                var elem = $( this );

                var oldColor = elem.attr("memColor");
                elem.css('background-color',oldColor);
             });
         };
    $('.me').resetColor();
    }(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="me" memColor="Red">Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="me" memColor="Blue">Lorem ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i've managed to change the color of my blocks for black by replacing oldColor with "black" in my first script. Maybe the problem comes from the use of the variable oldColor.

Comment: Did you do a debug of `this.attr("memColor")` and even `this` to see what you're working with? Also can you create a fiddle or something to see your exact situation?